# python pyodbc : how to connect to a specific instance

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

Am trying to connect to a specific instance of SQL Server and get some data from system tables. Am connecting using this code snippet:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=192.106.0.102;DATABASE=master;INSTANCE=instance1;UID=sql2008;PWD=password123;Trusted_Connection=yes')
...
cursorObj.execute("select * from sys.dm_os_sys_info")
row = cursorObj.fetchone()
print("rows from table ",row)
```

however am getting the values for the default instance only, but not able to get the value for 'instance1'. So, giving instance name in 'INSTANCE=instance1' really seems to have no effect. Even without it (tried giving 'PORT=1443', the instance's port number), am getting the values only for the default SQL Server instance. How to force it to get the values for the specific instance?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Authentication

First, you're providing both `uid`/`pwd` (SQL Server authentication) and `trusted_connection` (Windows authentication). Pick one, you can't use both. **I'll assume SQL Server authentication for the following examples.**

### Connection strings

Connecting to named instance *instance1* using the instance name:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=192.106.0.102\instance1;DATABASE=master;UID=sql2008;PWD=password123')
```

Connecting to named instance using TCP/IP using the port number *1443*:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=192.106.0.102,1443;DATABASE=master;UID=sql2008;PWD=password123')
```

### Keyword alternative

[pyodbc.connect()](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) supports keywords, I think these are easier to read and you don't have to do any string formatting if you're using variables for connection string attributes:

Named instance:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                               server='192.106.0.102\instance1',
                               database='master',
                               uid='sql2008',pwd='password123')
```

TCP/IP port:

```
connSqlServer = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}',
                               server='192.106.0.102,1443',
                               database='master',
                               uid='sql2008',pwd='password123')
```

Comment: This is "old" but I am commenting here because I am having different results. When I try 192.106.0.102\instance1 in the connection string, my login times out because the server cannot be found (of course I am using values correct for me).
I have seraching low and high and forthe life of me I cannot find out how to connect to a named instance. The "INSTANCE" keyword in the connection string doesn't do anything for me either.

Comment: @Jay Please ask a new question with your code (including connection string) and error message. The `instance` attribute above was invalid and has been removed.

Comment: Thanks - in fact, I do have a new question up already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363348/sqlalchemy-pyodbc-ms-sql-server-dsn-less-connection

Comment: I found I had to enter an additional slash to escape the slash for the instance. Worked great after that