# create a database using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, database, pyodbc

I am trying to create a database using `pyodbc`, however, I cannot find it seems to be paradox as the pyodbc needs to connect to a database first, and the new database is created within the linked one. Please correct me if I am wrong.

In my case, I used following code to create a new database

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server= serverName; database=databaseName; trusted_connection=true") 

cursor = conn.cursor()

sqlcommand = """
                   CREATE DATABASE ['+ @IndexDBName +'] ON  PRIMARY 
                    ( NAME = N'''+ @IndexDBName+''', FILENAME = N''' + @mdfFileName + ''' , SIZE = 4000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
                     LOG ON 
                    ( NAME = N'''+ @IndexDBName+'_log'', FILENAME = N''' + @ldfFileName + ''' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 100GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)'
             """

cursor.execute(sqlcommand)

cursor.commit()

conn.commit()
```

The above code works without errors, however, there is no database created.

So how can I create a database using pyodbc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you try to create a database with the default [autocommit](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#autocommit) value for the connection, you should receive an error like the following. If you're not seeing this error message, try updating the SQL Server native client for a more descriptive message:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
[SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
(226) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Turn on autocommit for the connection to resolve:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("driver={SQL Server};server=serverName; database=master; trusted_connection=true",
                      autocommit=True)
```

Note two things:

- `autocommit` is not part of the connection string, it is a separate keyword passed to the [connect](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Module#connect) function
- specify the initial connection database context is the `master` system database

**As an aside**, you may want to check the `@IndexDBName`, `@mdfFileName`, and `@ldfFileName` are being appropriately set in your T-SQL. With the code you provided, a database named `'+ @IndexDBName +'` would be created.

Comment: Sooo you didn't really explain what autocommit actually does?

Comment: @NoName - Since context is an ODBC driver for SQL Server, [Transactions in ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/odbc/performing-transactions-in-odbc?view=sql-server-ver15) may be helpful for details.

Comment: Thank you for explicitly pointing this out! I was wondering why the database wouldn't store my pawo change for the 'sa' account and have been researching about access permissions to no avail!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not work for me but I managed to create a database using the following code on Ubuntu:

```
conn_str = r"Driver={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1};" + f"""
    Server={server_ip};
    UID=sa;
    PWD=passwd;
"""
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name}")
```

Which uses the default "[master database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506339/11985094)" when connecting. You can check if the dataset is created by this query:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
```