# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, macos, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a remote sql server's database. Here is my py file;

```
import pyodbc
server = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx\sqlexpress'
database = 'db_name'
username = 'username'
password = 'passwrd'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=password')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table_name")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

I am getting this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connection.py", line 9, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=username;PWD=password')
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Try using [sqlserverport](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) to resolve the instance name to the corresponding port number.

Comment: I changed the server string as the following: `server = 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx,1433'`. Now this works in local connection. However I cannot connect it from an external IP. I think this is related with the server. The database user's rights should be checked right @GordThompson?

Comment: I solved this problem  in this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586977/12274302`