# pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc

Using the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Express, I can find the database and connect without problems.

But when I use pyodbc to connect to the same server using:

```
    import pyodbc
    Server = r"xxxER\xxxSQLSERV"
    db = "xxxDB"
    user = "xxx"
    password = "xxxx"
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server + ';DATABASE=' + db +';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + password)
```

By Using Pyhton in my local i am able to connect but when i am trying in linux server getting below error

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

i tried with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server too but facing the same issue.Can any one please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC drivers for Linux are unable to resolve instance names. You can use the free [sqlserverport](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlserverport) module to get the corresponding port number and use that to connect.

Comment: +1 for this! 
It goes without saying that `TCP/IP` should be enabled for the instance in question.
The `sqlserverport` module would crash with a key error for '`tcp` if it's not enabled for the specific SQL Server instance.

Comment: how can i check if the TCP/IP is enabled for the instance @Chukwuemeka

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, open SQL Server Configuration Manager and go through: the clicks: 

SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for {SQL Server Instance Name}  -> TCP/IP

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the instance from server and set it as

`Server = "xxxER"`

or if you have a port number append it as

`Server = "xxxER,portNo"`

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and solved my problem in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64586977/12274302).
Just add version.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server + ';DATABASE=' + db +';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + password)
```

If not work change version 17 to 13 if not to 11 .
[List versions of ODBC.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/release-notes-odbc-sql-server-windows?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Check your mssql network config, my problem was there.

Enable port 1433 for all IPs.

Now is working with IP and host name.

Answer (score 0):

I am using SSH Tunnel with remote server port forward to localhost,1433. This pyodbc connection intermittently fails if using the approach:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost, 1433;'...
```

Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 seems to be working all the time

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1, 1433;'

Incidentally also did same using Ruby and FreeTDS, and `Localhost,1433` worked all the time.. Must be something inside the pyodbc package or their approach that sometimes drop some info to make the DBMS on server fail to respond/timeout

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
mssql://DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER={server_address,PORT};DATABASE=<my_database>;UID=<my_username>;PWD=<my_password>
```