# Flask connection to Azure SQL database fail after deploy to Azure App service

Tags: python, database, azure, active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have flask app, that use ActiveDirectoryInteractive to authenticate connection with Azure SQL database with this code:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
            r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
            r'Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net,1433;'
            r'Database=REPORTING;'
            r'Uid=user.name@example.eu;'
            r'Encrypt=yes;'
            r'TrustServerCertificate=no;'
            r'Connection Timeout=30;'
            r'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive'
)
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
self.engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
```

When it's run locally - everything is fine. But after deploy to Azure app service, there is error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have "*Allow Azure services and resources to access this server*" check to YES, in SQL SERVER firewall settings

Comment: Have you tried with `timeout = Inf` ? Reference: [Login timeout expired connecting to serverless Azure SQL Database when paused](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/289#issuecomment-798976120)

Comment: You can refer to similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069846/pyodbc-operationalerror-hyt00-uhyt00-unixodbcmicrosoftodbc-driver-1

Comment: ActiveDirectoryInteractive, looks like the issue, do you have 2FA on?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.engine_azure = create_engine(conn_str, echo=True)
```

In the above connection statement, you need to pass the `timeout` parameter too which causes the connection's **SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT** attribute to be set before the connection is attempted. If the connection cannot be established within the given timeout (in seconds), an `OperationalError` exception will be raised.

Your create_engine statement will look like this:

```
create_engine(conn_str, connect_args={"timeout": 30})
```

Refer https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/The-pyodbc-Module#timeout for more details.