# Unable to connect to SQL server using pydobc, but it was working previously... Login timeout expired (0) SQLDriverConnect

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I was able to connect to SQL server previously, but now I am no longer able to connect.

The error is:

> OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

My connection code:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-312E8EK;'
                      'Database=Stocks;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Comment: Have you checked all the usual things connection time out debugging methods? You don't actually tell us what you have tried to fix the problem. Have you tried/checked anything?

Comment: `'Server=DESKTOP;'` This seems suspicious - and is inconsistent with your previous questions.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to do to fix it @larnu I tried repairing sql server files, but I don't really know what to check, since the connection string doesn't seem to need editing and it was working fine for the past few days

Comment: @SMor server=desktop is because that's from my other computer but the server name when I do select @@servername in ssms, shows DESKTOP for this one

Comment: Considering it's different to your last question, as @Smor noted, it would make sense to check the connection string.

Comment: can you give suggestions on what to change/check because I am running a script that has been working for the past few days and suddenly getting a connection error makes no sense as the connection string hasn't changed. could it be an error with pyodbc?

Comment: Your "other" questions use "localhost" as the server name - which is a special value that maps to the machine your app is running on. I suggest you try that. It is odd that you have two different sql server instances installed - one on each machine - which both contain a database named Stocks. Are you certain that is correct?

Comment: thanks for the reply @SMor - my other questions I just replaced the server name with localhost because I wasn't sure if that is "sensitive" information or not. When I run my actual scripts, the server name that shows up in select @@ servername is what I used to run them and they worked fine. I just opened up the same scripts that have not had any changes to them, and am trying to run them again, but the login timeout expired error just keeps showing up. Other than connection string, what else can I check for troubleshooting?

Comment: If something that was working previously suddenly stops working you need to identify what's changed about the situation. Has Windows Updates just executed updates and "helped things" by disabling required features or updating things in a broken way? Have you moved the script between computers? If "localhost" was working previously but the workstation name isn't working I'd suggest looking at: 1) is the SQL Server instance listening on an accessible IP address (SQL Server Express edition, for example, only listens on 127.0.0.1 by default)? 2) does Windows Firewall allow incoming connections?

Comment: Check Services.msc to see if SQL Server service stopped running. Start it if you can. BTW - `{SQL Server}` is an old ODBC Driver. Consider changing to the recommended: `{ODBC Driver XX for SQL Server}`. See [Differences Between Drivers for ODBC Drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39440008/1422451).

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52262859/2144390