# (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired in wsl 2

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I had a code which used pyodbc to connect with my sql server and it worked fine. Recently I upgraded to WSL2 for some work. Now when I try to run my code it gives me error " (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired".

What all things I did:

- Checked for Username and Password.
- Checked if it worked in SSMS.
- Checked if I have mentioned the correct port as mentioned over here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638867/19231561
- tried reinstalling sql on my ubuntu
- Checked if my TCP-IP is enabled.

It still didn't work. I could find a fellow mate facing the same issue but he didn't receive any answer : [Remote connection to MS SQL - Error using pyodbc vs success using SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635008/remote-connection-to-ms-sql-error-using-pyodbc-vs-success-using-sql-server-man)

Please suggest me what to do next. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
server = "DESKTOP-KI465GS"
database = "db"
username = "user"
password = "pwd"
port = "1433"

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(
    "driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server="
    + server
    + ","
    + port
    + ";database="
    + database
    + ";Uid="
    + username
    + ";Pwd="
    + password
    + ";Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Connection Timeout=30;"
)


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params
engine2 = create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}", fast_executemany=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using named pipes.

Try substitute the server name with its IP address and see if it works.

If it works go to sql server configuration manager and enable "Named Pipes" under "Protocols". Then you can use the server name instead of the ip address.

Comment: Hey, can you please confirm if this is what you meant with IP address :
` server = "127.0.0.1" `

I already have the Named Pipes enabled

Comment: If you are working on your machine without a tcp connection to a router, yes. If you are networked, find your assigned IP on the router and use that.